# Are channel sends preemption points for goroutine scheduling?

Tags: go, scheduling, channel, goroutine

From my understanding of Go scheduler, Go scheduling algorithm is [partially preemptive](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11462): goroutine switches happen when a goroutine is calling a function or blocking on I/O.

Does a goroutine switch happen when sending a message to a channel?

```
// goroutine A
ch <- message
// some additional code without function calls

// goroutine B
message := <- ch
```

In the code above, I want the code after `ch <- message` in A to be executed before switching to B, is this guaranteed? or does B get scheduled right after A sends a message on `ch`?

Comment: Relying on an implementation detail of the runtime is fraught with danger. I would reconsider your code.

Comment: Many times there is no runtime preemtion. Goroutines A and B may be running in different OS threads preemted by the kernel, or different CPU cores altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A's channel send can block, at which point it yields to the scheduler and you have no guarantee when A will receive control again. It might be after the code you're interested in in B. So the sample code has problems even with `GOMAXPROCS=1`.

Stepping back: when preemption happens is an implementation detail; it has changed in the past (there wasn't always a chance of preemption on function call) and may change in the future. In terms of the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem), your program is incorrect if it relies on facts about when code executes that happen to be true today but aren't guaranteed. If you want to block some code in B from running until A does something, you need to figure out a way to arrange that using channels or `sync` primitives.

And as user JimB notes, you don't even need to consider preemption to run into problems with the sample code. A and B could be running simultaneously on different CPU cores, and the code after the receive in B could run while the code after the send in A is running.

Answer (score 1):

My practical understanding of the language and runtime says that without you blocking explicitly after `ch <- message` and before invoking goroutine B, you have no guarantees that A will complete or run before B. I don't know how that is actually implemented but I also don't care because I accept the goroutine abstraction at face value. Don't rely on coincidental functionality in your program. Just going off your example, my recommendation would be to pass a channel into goroutine A and then block waiting to receive off it in order to serialize A and B.